# Suppose that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Prove that $X \sim f(1,v)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is what I'm supposed to prove...

Suppose that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent random variables with $Y \sim  z^2(v)$, and $Z \sim N(0,1)$, and $T = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{\frac{Y}{v}}}$. Let $X = T^2$. Prove that $X \sim f(1,v)$.

How would I start to prove this?

I know I should be using the theorem that states: If $U$ and $V$ are independent variable having square distribution with $V_1$ and $V_2$ degrees of freedom then $$F= \frac{\frac{U}{V_1}} {\frac{V}{V_2}}$$ is a random variable having an $F$ distribution for $f > 0$ and $g(f) = 0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

$X=T^2=Z^2/(Y/v)$.  $Z^2$ is the square of a standard normal random variable, so it is $\chi^2$ with $1$ degree of freedom.  $Y$ is (I assume) $\chi^2$ with $v$ degrees of freedom.  Now, apply the [theorem you mention above.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_distribution#Characterization)